# Hibernate - Many to many relationship: relationship table not getting populated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I've a class called Node that can have many Grades. And one grade can be associated with many Node objects. So many to many.
my annotations are like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_nodes")
public class Node {
 //getters setters, constructors.

  private Set<Grade> grades = new HashSet<Grade>();

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "nodes")
  public Set<Grade> getGrades() {
    return grades;
  }
}
```

// and here is grade class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="grades")
public class Grade {
  private Set<Node> nodes;
  // getters, setters, constructors

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "node_grade",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "grade_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "node_id")
  )
  public Set<Node> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
  }
}
```

both classes have @Id annotated ofcourse. For eg. for grade entity it would be:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="grade_id")
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
```

My grade table has 5 rows and a subset of the rows will be referenced when the relationship is made with a node object.
I'm using the following query to create a relation between node and grade.

```
// loads configuration and mappings
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
    registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();

    // builds a session factory from the service registry
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    // obtains the session
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    // List all grade 
    Query queryAllGrades = session.createQuery("FROM  Grade");
    List<Grade> allGrades = queryAllGrades.list();
    for(Grade grade: allGrades) {
      System.out.println("Grade::" + grade.getName());
    }

// Create a new Node
    Node node = new Node();
    node.addGrade(allGrades.get(0));

    session.save(node);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

But this only saves the Node object but this doesn't write to my table "node_grade" What am I missing?

even if I try to save the grade object it doesn't save the relationship in node_grade.

```
session.save(allGrades.get(0)); //doesn't save either the node or the node_grade

session.saveOrUpdate(allGrades.get(0)); //doesn't save either the node or the node_grade
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the inverse side of the association. Hibernate only cares about the owner side.

```
Node node = new Node();
session.save(node);
allGrades.get(0).addNode(node);
```

Comment: I can not thank you enough! You just made my day. But how do I know which one is the "Owner side" - node has multiple grade, and grade can be associated with multiple nodes?

Comment: The inverse side is the side with the `mappedBy` attribute.